# Laravel apis not working on https and gives error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https, self-signed-certificate

I am using laravel with linux server.

The laravel apis not working on https on my local and live server.

it gives error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

please guide me the way to add self sign certificate for api work on https or give me your suggestions what should be my steps.

I will appreciate best answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Only in Chrome)

This happened to me, and my solution was just go to the URL that returns this problem and type `thisisunsafe`.

I know this is not the best solution to solve this problem, but it helped in my local environment.